# How to limit an inner join in Sybase?

Tags: inner-join, limit, sybase, sap-ase

How can I limit an inner join or a subquery that it only selects one row? As it seems I can't use 'top 1' in my Sybase version (Sybase version: Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.5/EBF 19902) in subqueries.

Example

```
select * from A a
inner join B b on a.id = b.Aid
```

whereat table B has two records linked to table A (same Aid). But I'd like to join only one of these records.

I tried to replace the inner join with a subquery and using top 1, but this is not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here: https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/4-ways-to-join-only-the-first-row-in-sql.html

```
select * from A a
inner join (select * from B b where b.Aid in (select min(Aid) from B group by Aid) ) 
as b on b.Aid = a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Came across this post while going from "Sybase ASE doesn't support ROW_NUMBER()" to "TOP is not allowed in subqueries", to how tf do Sybase engineers expect us to limit a subquery result to 1 record? All solutions I've seen rely on min/max, but I haven't seen anything supporting a "ORDER BY" type of sorting.

So a simple

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.SEQUENCE, t.FROMDATE, t.FROMTIME)
```

becomes

```
select MYVALUE
  from (SELECT someExpression as MYVALUE,
               RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,1000000+fs.SEQUENCE), 6) || CONVERT(VARCHAR,t.FROMDATE, 23) || CONVERT(VARCHAR,t.FROMTIME) as SORTKEY
          FROM MY_TABLE t)
having SORTKEY = MIN(SORTKEY)
```

which is rather ugly, using all sorts of hacks to support string-sorting of the ORDER BY fields. As this will be used in subqueries, table alias scoping will mean that table joins need to be replicated.

The only alternative I can think of is a cursor with a break-condition so only the first row is processed, but that'll slow down things considerably.